# Jquery text function returns tags and js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am getting a text from elements that pop up on the page on change dome event (mutation). For every element that shows up I am collecting text from it. For the most websites, this approach works well but for some websites .text() returns tags and js scripts (it happens in gmail, outlook...)

```
var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach(async (mutation) => {
        console.log($(mutation.target).text())
    })
})
observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true })
```

It looks like it returns almost everything inside of the element. I have tried to return only mutations from current element that is mutated:

```
$(mutation.target).clone().children().remove().end().text()
```

This does not capture every text mutation on the page, unfortunately. Other things that I have tried are regex clean up (unreliable, cuts of some things that I need) And some js only code with no success. I wonder if there is another way to get a clean text from the dome element?

Comment: What about `mutation.target.innerText`?

Comment: @Rojo, I have tried it that. It renders the same results.

Comment: The site must have HTML tags encoded with entities so they're included as literal text.

Comment: @Barmar so there is no way to get clean text other than using the correct regex?

Comment: That *is* the clean text. Consider an HTML tutorial site, it will have lots of HTML tags displayed literally.

Comment: @Barmar I do not see those tags, style, and js code while I am checking my Gmail, and yet it will be returned by .text(). Probably there is something more there?

Comment: Maybe something is going on with CSS to hide them. Look at it DevTools

Comment: @Barmar I am using generic tools from devtools and I can't anything special. Is there anything specific I should use from devtools?

Comment: Use the Elements panel to see the DOM elements.